# Inserting of foreign key object inserts new object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

When I insert a new `MaskField` model into my database using Entity Framework Core it also inserts a `Restriction` model which is referenced inside the `MaskField` model. I am trying to get it to only reference a `Restriction` object as I already know the object exists when trying to reference it inside `MaskField`.

I have a `MaskField` model defined:

```cs
[Table("MaskField", Schema = "dbo")]
public class MaskField
{
    [Key]
    public int maskId { get; set; }
        public Restriction? restriction { get; set; }
}
```

That `MaskField` model references a single `Restriction` model inside it. This is the `Restriction` model:

```cs
[Table("Restriction", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Restriction
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int restrictionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? restrictionName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string? regex { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```cs
public class MaskContext : DbContext
{
    public MaskContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MaskField>((mf) =>
        {
            mf.HasKey(e => new { e.maskId });
            mf.HasOne(e => e.restriction).WithMany();
        });
    }

    public DbSet<MaskField> MaskFields { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Restriction> Restrictions { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to insert a `MaskField` that contains a restriction ends up executing:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Restriction] ([restrictionId], [regex], [restrictionName])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
```

Which ends up erroring because `IDENTITY_INSERT` is disabled. Any ideas on how to **just** reference it instead of it trying to insert a new `Restriction` model?

EDIT: This is the code for inserting a `MaskField`

```cs
public class MaskRepository : IMaskRepository
{
    MaskContext dbContext;
    public MaskRepository(MaskContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<MaskField> CreateAsync(Mask _object)
    {
        var obj = await dbContext.MaskFields.AddAsync(_object);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return obj.Entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you insert a `MaskField` ? Please paste the code.

Comment: EDITED: Added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a proper resolution to this problem.
You can add the `[JsonIgnore]` field to model classes to stop models from even being submitted to ef core in the first place.

In this case it will be:

```cs
[Table("MaskField", Schema = "dbo")]
public class MaskField
{
    [Key]
    public int maskId { get; set; }
    
    public int? restrictionId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Restriction? restriction { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a not so nice workaround for this.

So to just reference the `Restriction` is fairly simple just change the line
`public Restriction? restriction {get;set;}` to reference the key for `Restriction` like: `public int? restrictionId {get;set;}`

However since I wanted to extract the whole `Restriction` object in the one query I was forced to have both fields like this:

```cs
[Table("MaskField", Schema = "dbo")]
public class MaskField
{
    [Key]
    public int maskId { get; set; }
    
    public int? restrictionId { get; set; }
    public Restriction? restrictionId { get; set; }
}
```

This seems like a good solution until I realised that when saving/ updating that object to the database it causes the same original problem.

To work around this I have added logic in the saving and updating functions to set those fields to null before saving:

```cs
public class MaskRepository : IMaskRepository
{
    MaskContext dbContext;
    public MaskRepository(MaskContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<MaskField> CreateAsync(MaskField _object)
    {
        _object.restriction = null;

        var obj = await dbContext.MaskFields.AddAsync(_object);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return obj.Entity;
    }
}
```